# UK transit visa (Sri Lankan holding Schengen student visa )

Tags: uk, schengen, transit-visas, long-stay-visas

I'm a Sri Lankan national. I'm currently doing my M.Sc. in Norway. So I have a Schengen Student visa (temporary resident permit) which I renew every year.

My question is that if I want to transit via London Heathrow without entering the UK do I need a transit visa? Because the www.gov.uk site does mention that there are exemptions for people with long stay visa (Category D Visa) in EEA countries. I couldn't find any information about my specific situation. Is my Schengen Student visa (temporary resident permit) a category D visa which qualifies for transit in the UK without a visa?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

A residence permit is not the same as a category D visa.

However, if your residence permit is in the common format documented [here](http://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/?uri=CELEX:02002R1030-20080519) (scroll down), then it will separately exempt you from needing a direct airside transit visa for the UK.

Comment: thank you for the reply, yes I have the exact same resident card shown in the link. So does that mean I wont need a transit visa if I travel through London Heathrow?

Comment: @user71251: Yes, correct -- at least if the airline (who enforces the rules) implement the rules correctly. If you want complete certainty, contact your airline in the airport you're departing from _towards_ Heathrow.